# Looking for a regex to match more than one reference string in TortoiseSVN

Tags: regex, version-control, tortoisesvn

We used two different methods to reference external documents and Bugzilla bug numbers.

I'm now looking for a regular expression that matches these two possibilities of reference strings for convenient display and linking in the TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 log screen. First should be a bugzilla entry of the form `[BZ#123]`, second is `[some text and numbers]`, which has not to be converted into a url.

This can be matched with

```
\[BZ#\d+\]
```

and

```
\[.*?\]
```

My problem now is to concatenate those two match strings together. Usually this would be done by the regex (first|second), and I've done it this way:

```
(\[.*?\]|\[BZ#\d+\])
```

Unfortunately in this case TortoiseSVN seems to catch it all as the bug number because of the round braces. Even if I add a second expression which (according to the documentation) is meant to be used to extract the issue number itself, this second expression is supposed to be ignored:

```
(\[.*?\]|\[BZ#\d+\])
\[BZ#(\d+)\]
```

In this case TortoiseSVN displays the bug and document references correctly in the separate column, but uses them completely for the bugtracker url, which is of course not working:

```
https://mybugzillaserver/show_bug.cgi?id=[BZ#949]
```

BTW, Mercurial uses a better way by using {1}, {2}, ... as the placeholder in URLs.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

In short: We have used [BZ#123] as bug number references and [anytext] as references to other (partly non-electronic) documents. We would like to have both patterns listed in TortoiseSVN's extra column, but only the bug number from the first part shpuld be used as %BUGID% in the URL string.

**EDIT 2**

Supposedly TortoiseSVN cannot handle nested regex groups (round braces), so this question doesn't have any satisfactory answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TortoiseSVN regex, but what it looked like the problem was that the first piece of the regex (`[.*?\]`) would always match, so you would never even get to the part evaluating the second part, `\[BZ#(\d+)\]`

Try this one instead:

```
((?<=\[BZ#)\d+(?=\])|\[.*?\])
```

Explanation:

```
(           #Opening group.
(?<=\[BZ#)  #Look behind for a bugzilla placeholder.
\d+         #Capture just the digits.
(?=\])      #Look ahead for the closing bracket (probably not necessary.)
|           #Or, if that fails,
\[.*?\]     #Find all other placeholders.
)           #Closing the group.
```

---

**Edit:** I've just looked at TortoiseSVN docs. You could also try to keep the `Message part expression` the same, but change the `Bug-ID expression` to:

```
(?<=\[BZ#)(\d+)(?=\])
```

---

**Edit:** `?<=` represents a zero-width lookbehind. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. It is possible that TortoiseSVN doesn't support lookbehinds.

What happens if you just use `(\d+)` for your `Bug-ID expression`?

Comment: I tried now, and there is no sign at all in the Bug-ID column of TortoiseSvn. Additionally I do not recognize the pattern ?<= in your regex, nor could I find it in http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html. Could you please explain this to me?